# Having more than one data source

Tags: java, spring, datasource

I haven't found a question on this topic so I'll ask. I've never actually tackled something which uses more than one data source. One example would be [ETL](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract_Transform_Load) which requires two data sources. How could such an application be designed?

Comment: With `@EntityManager`, you can specify which data source you want to have an entity manager for, but I really don't see a specific question here.

Comment: For ETL two data sources are needed at the same time. I've found this [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?50123-JPA-with-multiple-persistence-units) and trying to make sense of it. I can see how to define two different EntityManagers in Spring configuration but what about defining two persistence units? Also I'd imagine the DAOs would be identical for the source and target database. Would there be a way to have two DAO instances with thier own EM from the same class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two data sources, two separate names.  Inject each one by their respective bean IDs.

```
<bean id="fromDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${from.jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${from.jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${from.jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${from.jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="from.jdbc.properties"/>

<bean id="toDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${to.jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${to.jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${to.jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${to.jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="to.jdbc.properties"/>
```

You'd want to have a single DAO, but two instances of it - each with their own data source.  One would SELECT from the source, the other would INSERT into the target.

A better way might be to forego Spring and just use bulk transfer mechanisms built into the databases.

Comment: Thanks duffymo. About the two data sources, how can I define different connection settings? I'm used to having a single persistence.xml. Also, in the case where the structure of the source and destination database are practically identical, would you define different DAO classes?